# Make install fails at the end (buildroot)

Tags: automake, buildroot

I'm cross-compiling ecasound, which goes well up to the point that all binaries get compiled, but fails during (at the end of?) the installation phase.

The thing is, I don't see any error message or anything, so I'm left guessing here:

```
ecasound: installs files in /home/buildroot/buildroot-2018.02-rc2/output/target//home/buildroot/buildroot-2018.02-rc2/output
make[1]: *** [/home/buildroot/buildroot-2018.02-rc2/output/build/ecasound-2.9.1/.stamp_target_installed] Error 1
make: *** [_all] Error 2
```

Full output: https://pastebin.com/ca6FJebB (hope this contains enough details)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It did work after first doing a complete build, followed by ecasound seperately, indicating it was missing dependencies. Turned out the missing piece here was: `BR2_PACKAGE_PYTHON_CURSES`.

In case anyone wants to build ecasound for buildroot, a working package is available in my github account.. Not sure if it's clean code/by the book, but it works..

Answer (score 1):

Presumably the ecasound 'make install' returns (silently?) with an error. We don't have an ecasound package in upstream Buildroot, so it is hard to know what you are doing, but the install location (../output/target/home/buildroot/..) certainly looks wrong.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is your install path somehow duplicated itself

/home/buildroot/.../target//home/buildroot/...

I have seen this several times too, and havent really found a way to fix it except to make clean & make again